# Javascript concept to run all test cases

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, authentication, testcase

I am trying to run all the possible test cases for a loginValidation function to be  included in my project.

**Here is LoginValidation Login** :

```
let checkLogin = (email, password, allUsers) => {
let isUserFound = false;
let passwordCorrect = false;
for (currentUser in allUsers){
console.log(currentUser);

  if(allUsers[currentUser]['email'] === email){

      if(allUsers[currentUser]['password'] === password){
           isUserFound= true;
           passwordCorrect=true;
           break;
      }else{
           isUserFound= true;
           passwordCorrect=false; break;
      }

 }else{
       isUserFound = false;
  }

}//loop ends

 if(isUserFound === true && passwordCorrect === true){
       console.log('You are logged in');
 }else if(isUserFound  === true && passwordCorrect === false){
       console.log('You have provided incorrect password');
 }else{
     console.log('No user with this email found');
  }
};
```

**To run the code**

```
checkLogin('emailid1@email.com','password1',allUsers);
```

Now my question is in many ways can **allUsers** be defined.

My solution for **allUsers** .

```
  let allUsers = {
         '1':{'email':'emailid1@email.com','password':'password1'},
         '2':{'email':'emailid2@email.com','password':'password2'},
         '3':{'email':'emailid3@email.com','password':'password3'},
         '4':{'email':'emailid4@email.com','password':'password4'}
      };
```

Considering all users to be an Object. What if someone has an **array of allUsers**, and they try to call the function by

```
 checkLogin('emailid1@email.com','password1', ...allUsers);
```

How should  **allUsers** be defined to make it pass in all use-cases .

Comment: you are not really having an object with _all users'_ passwords, do you?

Comment: @Jeff basically you are right , its an associative array.

Comment: Just to be clear: this will be your login-system _in production_? Or is this just to test the validator? The first one should defenitely not be done.

Comment: This is just to validate the test so that i can write my production login accordingly with ES6 standards.